# HP-3670 Scanner on Ubuntu 12.04 machine

Tags: 12.04, scanner

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. When I connect my HP-3670 Scanner the mouse stops working. Both mouse and scanner are connected through USB ports. How can I resolve this issue?